# Excel Formula - IF statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a table that tracks fuel expenses for a vehicle. The first 2 columns are for speedometer reading and total KM's. The Total KM's is calculated by subtracting previous speedo reading from current one and inserting the difference.

I have one row for each day but my problem is that if I don't fill up, then the formula I have at present means it uses value zero for speedo which in turn gives me a negative reading (to the value of last speedo reading) for KM's.

How do I write an IF statement that says, if the speedo value is zero (or has no value), then look back up column for last cell with a value?

Picture of worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Well, for this to work, could you please show us sample data, you own attempt in the form of a formula and some indication about "current", because you would need some value to start your calculations with in the first row.

Comment: you are probably better off dating each entry rather than each row being a day.

Answer (score 0):

*To get proper results you need to test Blank Cell with the Formula.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `D111`:

  ```
  =IF(OR(ISBLANK(B111),ISBLANK(C111)),0,(C111-B111))
  ```
- Enter this Formula in Cell `E111`:

  `=IF(ISBLANK(D111),0,(D111*70))`

**When `C111` in blank:**

[image]

**N.B.**

- You may create new Column for Daily expenses value , since I've used `70` to multiply with `Tot KMs`,, `(D111*70))`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*